# Improper operand type error using __asm

Tags: c++, assembly

What does improper operand type mean?

I'm trying to convert some c++ code into assembler

```
     temp_char = OChar[i]         //temp_char is a character and OChar is array and i is the index
```

ive tried

```
     mov eax, i
     mov temp_char, [eax+OChar]
```

and also

```
     mov eax, i
     movsx temp_char, [eax+OChar]
```

can anyone explain how i can avoid the improper operand type?

this is the full code

```
                  char temp_char;                       
                   int i;

   __asm{       

            mov i,0
            jmp checkend

     startfor:      mov eax,i   
            add eax,1
            mov i,eax



   checkend:        cmp i,length    
            jge endloop     
            movsx   temp_char, [eax+OChars] 

            //encryption of string//
            push eax                
            and eax,0xAA            
            not al                  
            mov edx,eax             
            pop eax                 
            and eax,0x55            

            xor ecx,edx             
            xor ecx,eax             
            rol cl,2                

            sub al,0x20
                            pop ebp                             

            //end of encryption//
            movsx   [eax+EChars], temp_char 
            jmp startfor        
   endloop:     ret

}
```

Comment: What are you **actually** trying to do? Which line gets that error?

Comment: the mov temp_char, [eax+OChars]

Comment: You're trying to move an array into a register. That's no bueno.

Comment: Also, `asm` is non-standard, so you'd need to post the compiler. Furthermore, it seems like you're not posting the full code, which makes this question unanswerable : please post more info.

Comment: its inside a for loop and encrypts a string that is put into an array

Answer (score 5):

You can't move stuff directly from memory to memory on x86 - you have to go through a register - along the lines of:

```
 mov eax, i
 mov bx, word ptr [eax+OChar]
 mov temp_char, bx
```

Comment: its saying operand size conflict on mov temp_char, bx

Comment: What is temp_char declared as?