# Can't access value of element on array in assembly

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86

I'm using Visual Studio and I get the following error message:

> error C2415: improper operand type

This is my code:

```
int v[] = { 2, 3, 6, 4, 23, 9, 6, 54, 3, 7, 11 };
int num;

__asm
{
    lea eax, v
    mov num, [eax]
}
```

If I use eax instead of [eax] I can get the memory address into the num variable, but the compiler doesn't let me take the element in that position.

Comment: What is your question? Which line is indicated as causing the error message?

Comment: On x86 the `mov` command doesn't take two memory operands.

Comment: Maybe following SO thread will help you - it seems to be a similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406506/improper-operand-type-error-using-asm

Comment: `Mov` the value into a register then `mov` the contents of that register to `num`

Comment: Michael Petch, you are right! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Petch mentioned, `mov` command doesn't take two memory operands.